# Where should I put test classes if they ARE the project?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, acceptance-testing

Using maven there is the standard folder structure:

```
Project/src/main/java/com/application/Class.java
Project src/test/java/com/application/ClassTest.java
```

In this case both the original class and its test have the same package

```
package com.application;
```

**But where should I put test classes if the whole purpose of the project is to do acceptance test of another project, e.g. a REST api?**

So far I have used the above structure and had utility classes in `...src/main...`and the tests in `...src/test...`but this does not make sense since the test classes are not testing the utility classes.

**Is there a best practice for this?**

Comment: I don't know if there's established best practice, but I would put everything in main. The project's main deliverable is something that tests something else -- but that's besides the fact that the source code is for the main deliverable. If you have non-trivial code for those tests that you're testing (ie, "a test for the tests"), _that_ would go into `src/test`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the reasoning for this structure?  Why aren't the test classes part of the same project?  How would a developer know he/she broke a unit test if the unit test is located in some other project?  How is a large refactoring handled if the existing unit tests aren't updated at the same time?  Are these really unit tests, or are they integration (ITCase) tests?

Comment: I would suggest you to move the util classes as well to src/test since they are test utils.

Comment: You could create a maven-module named "acceptance-test".

Comment: @AndrewS: I think people simply decided "Oh we need acceptance test for this REST API!" (Note: I am not talking about unit tests) and created a new project and repository for this. And then It just stayed there.